# How to display all the attribute values of product attribute?

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I'm new to Magento and I'm developing E-commerce site in Magento 2.

I have created an **attribute "Power Type" (MultiSelect)** and gave 4 options to it and assigned it to "**default**" Attribute set.

I created a product with "default" attribute selected and selected 3 options from the 4 options given in "Power Type" attribute.
Now when I show these options on Product view,

**I want to show all of them with the option that is not selected to be grayed out.**

Right now I'm using following code in my phtml file to retrieve the attribute values

```
$_powertypes = $_product->getAttributeText("power_types");
```

Above code gives me value of that attribute that is for a product selected. I want all the four options that were made during the creation of attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just keep below code reference to get all option of attribute,

Inside your **block** file,

```
<?php
    protected $eavAttributeRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,       
        \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $eavAttributeRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->eavAttributeRepository = $eavAttributeRepository;
    }

    public function getOptionlist($attributeCode){
        $attributes = $this->eavAttributeRepository->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,$attributeCode);
        $options = $attributes->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
        return $options;                
    }

}
?>
```

Inside your **phtml** file,

```
<?php
    $optionList = $block->getOptionlist('power_types');
    foreach ($optionList as $value) {
        //print_r($value);
       echo $value['label'];
    }
?>
```